# "The provided resource.properties.tenantId 'null' is invalid" when trying an az deployment

Tags: azure-cli

I'm trying to test a deployment with

```
> az deployment sub what-if --location uksouth --template-file .\main.bicep --verbose
```

and I get the following error message which isn't very useful.

> InvalidTemplateDeployment - The template deployment 'main' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'. See inner errors for details.
> BadRequest - The provided resource.properties.tenantId 'null' is invalid.

How can I find out which resource the error "The provided resource.properties.tenantId 'null' is invalid" refers to?

Additionally, when running with `--debug` I see the following error:

```
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", line 109, in handle_template_based_exception
AttributeError: 'InvalidTemplateError' object has no attribute 'inner_exception'
...
```

which looks like a bug in the Azure CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged* the issue and found the root cause to be that I'd missed some `createTenantProperties` from my Azure B2C Directory.

I had

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2023-01-18-preview' = {
  name: 'foo.onmicrosoft.com'
  location: 'Europe'
  tags: {
    Environment: 'Prod'
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'PremiumP1'
    tier: 'A0'
  }
}
```

and I needed

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2023-01-18-preview' = {
  name: 'foo.onmicrosoft.com'
  location: 'Europe'
  tags: {
    Environment: 'Prod'
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'PremiumP1'
    tier: 'A0'
  }
  properties: {
    createTenantProperties: {
      countryCode: 'GB'
      displayName: 'Foo Foo Foo'
    }
  }
}
```

* regarding "debugging" I resorted to the tried and true "comment everything out then comment things back in one at a time and see where it breaks" method. Really the error messaging needs improving in the Azure CLI

Comment: Can you open a github issue so we can track it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues